# How can I jump between buttons in Emacs?

Tags: button, emacs, elisp

I create some buttons in my major mode with:

```
(insert-text-button "Start" :type 'start-btn)
...
(insert-text-button "Button2" :type 'b2-btn)
```

I want to jump to the next and prev. buttons from the cursor position.

I don't know how to detect button position. Give me a hint.

```
(defun jump-to-next-button ()
  "Jump to the next text button from current position."
  (interactive)
  ;; magic
  )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buttons inserted with `insert-text-button` and related functions use the `button` text property, which you can search for with [`next-single-property-change`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Property-Search.html). The "magic" part would then look like this:

```
(goto-char (or (next-single-property-change (point) 'button)
               (point-max)))
```